# focus_set() in Python does not work on second window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

The `getinput` window appears after the intro window and should focus on the entry space, but doesn't.  If I skip the intro window then the focus takes place.  If I then enter a number outside the range 1-10 the `getinput` window reappears, but without focus. Can anybody please help?

## Written in Python 3.3.5

```
import tkinter

def intro(tkinter):
    global contents
    w = 300
    h = 200
    frame = tkinter.Frame(root,width=w,height=h)
    frame.pack()
    label = tkinter.Label(frame,font=('courier', 12, 'bold'),\
        text="\nPlease click on OK.\n\n")
    label.pack()
    label.place(x=40,y=50)
    OK = tkinter.Button(root,bd=5,text='OK',font=('courier', 20, 'bold'),\
        command=root.destroy)
    OK.pack()
    OK.place(x=125,y=120)
    root.mainloop()

def cancel():
    global level
    level = contents.get()
    root.destroy()

def getinput(tkinter):
    global contents
    w = 400
    h = 300
    frame = tkinter.Frame(root,width=w,height=h)
    frame.pack()
    label = tkinter.Label(frame,font=('courier', 12, 'bold'),\
        text="Please enter a number in the\n range 1 to 10 and click on OK.")
    label.pack()
    label.place(x=40,y=50)
    entry = tkinter.Entry(frame,font=('courier', 24, 'bold'))
    entry.pack()
    entry.place(x=175,y=150,width=50)
    contents = tkinter.StringVar()
    contents.set("")
    entry["textvariable"] = contents
    entry.focus_set()       #Gives focus by flashing cursor in entry space.
    OK = tkinter.Button(root,bd=5,text='OK',font=('courier', 20, 'bold'),\
        command=cancel)
    OK.pack()
    OK.place(x=170,y=210)
    root.mainloop()

level = ""
contents = ""
root = tkinter.Tk()     #Comment out this line
intro(tkinter)          #and this line to skip intro window
root = tkinter.Tk()
getinput(tkinter)
while (int(level) < 1) or (int(level) > 10):
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    getinput(tkinter)

print('Result is ',level)
```

Comment: I did not understand exactly your problem, but when I click `OK` a new window appears and the `Entry` object is focused and ready to be written on my system. Which system are you using?

Comment: Part of the problem is likely due to multiple instances of `Tk` -- you should only ever have one. If you need more than one window, create instances of `Toplevel`.

Comment: I don't think the problem is the multiple `Tk` instances, since they never run at the same time. I think that the focus is actually set to the `entry`, but the problem is that the window doesn't have the focus. You can force focus to the widget by using `entry.focus_force()`. This should also bring focus to the window.

Comment: Apart from that, there's some strange things in your code. For one, you shouldn't use both `pack` and `place`, pick one and stick to it. The is absolutely no reason to call both on the same widget. Also, why are you passing `tkinter` to your functions? You don't have to pass it to use it inside the function. Also you don't have to set your `StringVar` to `""`, since that's what it initializes to.

Comment: Many thanks to all of you.  entry.focus_force() does the trick but I'll certainly tidy the program up taking your other comments into account.

Answer (score 0):

I got a same issue. Thank @fhdrsdg, `entry.focus_force()` figure that out. Below is an example.

```py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
Window = Frame(root)
Window.pack()
txt = Entry(Window)
txt.pack()
txt.focus_set()
root.mainloop()

root = Tk()
Window = Frame(root)
Window.pack()
txt = Entry(Window)
txt.pack()
txt.focus_force()
root.mainloop()
```